# Permgen issue when using Spring's LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: spring, tomcat, c3p0, sessionfactory, permgen

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration
{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource()
    {

        String datasourcePathStartsWith = "datasource.";

        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try
        {
            dataSource.setContextClassLoaderSource("library");
            dataSource.setPrivilegeSpawnedThreads(true);
            dataSource.setDriverClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty(datasourcePathStartsWith + "url"));
            dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty(datasourcePathStartsWith + "user"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty(datasourcePathStartsWith + "password"));
            dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(datasourcePathStartsWith + "minPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(datasourcePathStartsWith + "maxPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setCheckoutTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(datasourcePathStartsWith + "checkoutTimeout")));
            dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(datasourcePathStartsWith + "maxIdleTime")));
            dataSource.setMaxStatements(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(datasourcePathStartsWith + "maxStatements")));
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }


}
```

Here is my code. It works "fine" on Tomcat 7 - when I redeploy application many times and use "Find leaks" feature, it shows nothing. But if I add sessionFactory, problems appears every redeploy:

*The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak (use a profiler to confirm):
  /testPermGen

  /testPermGen

  /testPermGen*

```
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
```

I tried this code, without wiring to dataSource, no success. Looks like the problem is with unclosed LocalSessionFactoryBean on application stop.

```
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
```

Tomcat is running with following flags:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

It is possible to fix this problem with memory leaks?

## UPDATE:

I've uploaded the whole project (4 files) on GitHub to reproduce the memory leak: https://github.com/anton-09/TestPermGen

Mattias Jiderhamn's classloader-leak-prevention didn't help a lot, I've got this log in Tomcat 7:

```
июл 03, 2017 11:44:27 AM se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.JULLogger warn
WARNING: Waiting for Thread 'Thread[Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close(),5,main]' of type com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5 loaded by protected ClassLoader with contextClassLoader = protected ClassLoader or child for 5000 ms. Thread stack trace: 
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:300)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOLOGOFF(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:61)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:543)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:3984)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:642)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:255)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:622)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1076)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1101)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1062)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1316)
июл 03, 2017 11:44:27 AM se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.JULLogger info
INFO: Thread 'Thread[Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close(),5,main]' of type com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5 loaded by protected ClassLoader with contextClassLoader = protected ClassLoader or child no longer alive - no action needed.
```

Looks like everithing ok, but Tomcat's "find leaks" reports about new memory leak.

## SOLUTION

The problem was with JBoss logging included in Hibernate dependency. I excluded jboss-logging dependency from hibernate-core, copied jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar to Tomcat's "lib" folder and the problem went away.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try another connection pool implementation? Spring Boot for example supports (in order of preference): Tomcat, HikariCP, DBCP (deprecated), DBCP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many third party libraries](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2012/02/26/classloader-leaks-v-common-mistakes-and-known-offenders/) that may cause ClassLoader leaks. If you want to track down the offender in your case (which could be both fun and educational!), I recommend following the instructions in [this blog post of mine](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/). To get rid of the issue, simply add [my ClassLoader Leak Prevention library](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention) to your application. The offender is sometimes also revealed just by watching the logs after adding that library.

Comment: I know the offender - it's C3P0 library. Your classloader didn't help, I've updated my question with Tomcat logs

Comment: When you say it didn't help, what does it mean? Server eventually crashes with OutOfMemoryError? Tomcat still logging "...but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory..."?

The problem may not be C3PO itself but the Oracle driver, which has been known to cause leaks. Is it possible for you to try another database?

Comment: Tomcat reports about classes, still loaded in memory. After a number of stop/start operations I got PermGen OutOfMemory error. I was wrong about C3P0 (maybe). I've just tried another database (mysql) and another connection pool library (hikari) with the same result! The only way I can fix this issue is to fully comment sessionFactory bean!! Maybe it's Spring's fault?

Comment: I'd be interrested to find the reason for this. Please try to get a heap dump. Two ways to do that are described at http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/, but there are more options, depending on your OS (kill -3, Ctrl+Break). If you are not able to analyze it by yourself, maybe you could make it available to me for analysis?

Comment: I put heap dump here (15Mb): https://www.dropbox.com/s/jx40c01nvzuehxg/java_pid6536.rar?dl=0
I also tried to analyze it with Eclipse MAT and I see problems with class com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread

Comment: The leak is caused by JBoss Logging doing logging via JUL (java.util.logging) using a custom log level, `org.jboss.logging.JDKLevel` (which is in your WAR). You should be able to get around this by moving JBoss Logging to the application server level, or reconfigure the logging.

Comment: Brilliant! I excluded jboss-logging dependency from hibernate-core, copied jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar to Tomcat's "lib" folder and the error went away. Can you tell me (maybe via screenshot) how did you find this leak? I want to try to fix my full app myself

Comment: How to find the leaks in the dump is described in the blog post that is linked in the answer we are commenting; http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/

Comment: I added automatic leak prevention for custom `java.util.logging.Level`s. Would you care compiling https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention from sources and give it a try with your project (with jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar removed from Tomcat and re-added to the WAR) before I release to Maven Central?

Comment: The prevention for this leak has been released in version 2.3.0 of my library